# Movie where a creature (monster) wears a wedding dress

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie around 80s to 90s.

I remember the part about a monster creature, who wore a wedding dress and was about to marry the kid's dad. She changed her skin from a kind of green lizard-like or alligator-like but little creepy into human skin. Some kids found out this woman is not human; he tried to tell his father about it but he don't believe him.

Some kids went to the cave to free some people whom she had kidnapped.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: see OP confirmation comment for answer below

Answer (score 3):

"Stepmonster"(1993)?

She does have skin that's lizard or alligator-like and it ends in a cave, like you described, with her victims being found in cocoons? I think? Here is the official trailer from Youtube.

Comment: Yes this! Thank you so much for help! :)

Comment: @AMS If this answered your question, then would you please to be so considerate as to click the green checkmark in the left column beside this answer.  It awards you and the person who answered some points, among other things!